# Creating global object in Rails automatically

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oop

I have a library with a class that, when created, will automatically scrape data from a series of FTP servers periodically. It is threaded and you can simply call a 'results' method to see the results thus far. I am fairly new to rails but I wanted to create a web interface for this object that allowed one to see the results, start it, stop it, and basically just interact with the object in general. I want it to be created first thing and remain intact regardless of if anyone is using the web interface so that it can run in the background and collect data. I also want it to be accessible from a controller so that I can have start/stop/info pages. Any ideas on the best way to achieve this?

P.S. I am running Rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: so your storage options would appear to be: Database, Remote Storage (s3), Filesystem (local), and memory.  Which of these do you need and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's better ways to run a background process and access it from a rails app, but to directly answer your question:

Just put it in an initializer. There's a /config/initializers directory. Put a .rb file in there and it will automatically run when your rails app is started.

/config/initializers/hello.rb:

```
Rails.logger.debug "Hello World"
```

Start your rails server and you'll see "Hello World"

To make the instance of your class globally available just create a global var:

```
MYCLASS = MyClass.new
```

Comment: Thanks. I will convert to Redis if necessary, but this web app will be rarely used and behind a firewall so security and scaling is not much of an issue. If what tadman says is true and multiple instances get started, I will have to look for a more elegant solution, but thank you for being direct.

Comment: So what happens when there are multiple instances of Rails running? Don't you end up with multiple processes? Though this would be okay if you were calling the code to start a process via some other means, such as `/etc/init.d/MyThing start`...as I suggested elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating threads inside of your Rails application. This is messy, dangerous, and since Rails is not a singular process but a number of them created by your launcher framework, such as Passenger, then you will need to have an instance of this object in each process which will likely duplicate effort.

A better approach is to have a singular process that runs in the background but that exposes an API of some sort that can be used by your various Rails instances. One way to do this is to use a system like Memcached, Redis, a conventional database, or even flat files as a shared storage system. Another way is to respond to API calls directly by exposing an interface that can be used by Rails. Making a process that "speaks memcached" is not too difficult.

Generally the easiest approach is to use shared storage to get the job done. It's easy to use, and it's even easier to inspect to see if the process is producing the correct results. For instance, use ActiveRecord to save the results of your scraping into a database and use these same models to fetch the data back out inside your application.

What you build into your Rails application is some kind of wrapper to access this shared data. This could be a series of ActiveRecord models, a few Memcached calls, or something else, but the end result would be a clean interface that can run independently in N processes.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Is this running on a Linux box?

If so, you can easily write a daemon & optionally have it start when the system boots. I'd put the data & probably its current state (running/off) into some sort of memory store (Memcache? Redis) or a database. Your controller access the data from there.

You could also have your controller do something like `/etc/init.d/my_service stop/start/restart` directly.

If you were going to have lots of these little daemons running, potentially on (or managed by) different machines, I'd recommend writing an app to manage their state & communicating with it via something like RabbitMQ, but that may be overkill for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Redis and Resque are what you want -- along with your rails app.

Redis: http://redis.io/

Resque: https://github.com/defunkt/resque

Redis is a caching server and resque is a job scheduling tool built on top of it. Resque has lots of extensions that work with it that let you customize and extend its behavior. For example:

- https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status - Resque Status (allowing you to monitor progress and information from running jobs while they run)
- https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler Resque Scheduler (allowing you to lunch jobs interactively, or launch jobs on a regular, cron-like schedule)
- https://github.com/jayniz/resque-loner - Resque Loner (allows you to make sure you have only one instance of a job queued to run at a time)

Resque also comes with a web ui that allows you to track the status of all your jobs and queues.

So I'd build your app basically by creating a page that allows you to launch jobs -- or monitor the completion or progress of jobs that are running.

All your jobs will run on a 'worker' server and will be independent of what happens with the rails app. All progress data will be stored in redis so if your rails app restarts, you just connect to redis when it restarts and you have current data.

All this infrastructure works really well on Heroku as well using their 'Redis-to-Go' add-on. I use it for a number of tasks currently and it works great.